# if statement + stop in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

**Background:**

I have two elements in an R function called **GG** (see my R code below), **type** and **width**. The **type** element simply can only take the following character arguments:  "**normal**" or "**cauchy**". When `type` is "cauchy" `width` can be any number OR it can be one of the following 3 words: "**medium**", "**wide**", or "**very wide**". However, when `type` is "**normal**", `wide` *must only be a number*.

**Question:**

First, when I run `GG(type = "normal", width = "medium")` the function should **STOP** and return a message, but I get an error, how can I fix that?

Second, could these if statements be more efficiently written?

```
GG = function(type, width){


width <- if(type == "cauchy" & width == "wide") { sqrt(2)/2 } else

if(type == "cauchy" & width == "medium") { 1/2 } else 
  if(type == "cauchy" & width == "very wide") { 1 } else 
    if(type == "normal" & is.character(width) ) {
      stop(message(cat("You must provide a number")))
    } else { width }

return(width)

}

GG(type = "normal", width = "medium") ## if you I run this, I get an error.
```

Comment: Make arguments to GG a list. One argument to the function then extract named items.

Comment: @42-, could you possibly provide an answer?

Comment: as an aside, use `stop("You must provide a number")`

Comment: The `stop()` function triggers an error. That's how it works. Not sure exactly what you were expecting.

Comment: @MrFlick, I meant I get an additional "bug" not aside from the STOP.

Comment: And what is that bug you are getting exactly?

Comment: @MrFlick, `Error in Prior(type = "normal", width = "wide") : 
Called from: Prior(type = "normal", width = "wide")
Browse[1]> Q`

Comment: @parvinkarimi how about you restart your session and try the example i provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, stop is an error message

> stop stops execution of the current expression and executes an error action.

so it is unsurprising that this is an error, but it is doing exactly what you want, which is stopping and returning a message.

42's suggestion might have meant something along these lines:

```
GG2 <- function(type, width) {

  width_vals <- list(
    "wide" = sqrt(2)/2,
    "medium" = 1/2,
    "very wide" = 1
  )

  if (type == "normal" & is.character(width)) {
    stop("You must provide a number")
  } else if (type == "cauchy") {
      width <- width_vals[[width]]
  }
  return(width)
}


GG2(type = "normal", width = 2) # 2
GG2(type = "normal", width = "wide") # error
GG2(type = "cauchy", width = "wide") # 0.7071068
GG2(type = "cauchy", width = "medium") # 0.5
GG2(type = "cauchy", width = "very wide") # 1
```